# Return last n elements from lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm new to Haskell and currently trying to understand pattern matching. So would it be possible to get the last 3 elements from a list like this one:
`[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [5,6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,13]]` to return something like this `[(4,5,6), (7,8,9), (11,12,13)]`?

here's my code

```
lastElems [] = []
lastElems ((x:xs):ys) = drop (length xs - 3) xs : lastElems ys
```

I think it does what it supposed to do but it returns as lists in a list instead of tuples.
Could anyone please give me a hint on how to tackle this?

And does this also mean that you can't use (:) with tuples? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `drop n xs` returns a list, not a tuple. It might be better to use recursion here.

Comment: Thanks! Would a recursion with `last` somehow work in this case? I understand that `last` only returns the last item. But what do I do if I want more than one item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:drop) takes an `Int` and a list `[a]`, and returns an `[a]`. This also makes sense since the number is arbitrary, and thus we can not know at compile time how many elements the list will have.

We can however make use of explicit recursion to retrieve the last three elements:

```
last3 :: [a] -> (a, a, a)
last3 [x1, x2, x3] = (x1, x2, x3)
last3 (_:xs@(_:_:_:_)) = last3 xs
```

then `lastElems` is just a mapping of `last3`:

```
lastElems :: [[a]] -> [(a, a, a)]
lastElems = map last3
```

this function of course does not work for lists with less than three elements.

Comment: Thank you Willem! I'll have to start learning recursion sooner than I thought :)